# Buy items from Amazon programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm looking for a way to buy stuff from amazon (like toilet paper, eggs, etc) goods I use on a weekly basis automatically via one of their APIs.

I'm aware that http://zinc.io/ is able to do this, but being a third party enterprise solution, I'm thinking there is a hefty price tag involved and am searching for possible alternative solutions.

Comment: Do you mind which language the program is written in?

Comment: Please provide more information! Your question is too broad!

Comment: Any language is fine, my assembly is a bit rusty but if that's what its in, I'll take it.

Comment: Also, which amazon version? .co.uk? .com? I don't know if they use the same HTML id attributes...

Comment: @Constantine - Hmm..I'll clear up my use case then.  For example, I'd like to have toilet paper, paper towels, etc delivered to me weekly.  Now, I'd to have a way to communicate with Amazon via API which would take my order and payment information. I'm wondering if Amazon has an API that can do that.

Comment: @user184994 It sounds like your line of thinking is following along the use of a bot.  Otherwise I don't see how front-end html id attr fit in.  I was hoping for a type of API call amazon already provides as part of their developer program.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realise they had an API for it. I was thinking in terms of a bot, yes.

Comment: @user184994 I'd prefer an API, in case there isn't one I'd build a bot.